# Adding a custom class to blockquote in QuillJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill, vue-quill-editor

I'm trying to figure out how to add a custom class when the user clicks the blockquote toolbar button. At the moment, when blockquote is clicked, the element is created as so:

```
<blockquote class="ql-align-justify">this is my quoted text</blockquote>
```

I would like to add `.blockquote` to the class as so:

```
<blockquote class="ql-align-justify blockquote">this is my quoted text</blockquote>
```

I'm currently looking at adding a handler, but there doesn't appear to be much documentation on how this works:

```
 this.editor = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, this.editorOptions)
 // Handlers can also be added post initialization
 var toolbar = this.editor.getModule('toolbar');
 toolbar.addHandler('blockquote', function(value) {
    //todo: working on adding the blockquote class to blockquotes.
    console.log('blockquote called');
    console.log('value:');
    console.log(value);

    if (value) {
       this.quill.format('blockquote');
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think handlers can do this (as far as I know)

But you can extend the  BlockQuote format, by doing so, you will have full control of the node, you can add classes, or even click handler.

The format that is responsible for blockquote is:

```
const BlockQuote = Quill.import('formats/blockquote');
```

So simply you can do:

```
  const BlockQuote = Quill.import('formats/blockquote');

  class CustomBlockQuote extends BlockQuote {
    static create(value) {
      const node = super.create(value);
      node.classList.add('test');
      return node;
    }
  }
```

And you can update the tag name and the blot name like:

```
  CustomBlockQuote.blotName = 'custom-blockquote';
  CustomBlockQuote.tagName = 'blockquote';
```

Or even simpler for only changing the class:

```
  class CustomBlockQuote extends BlockQuote {}
  CustomBlockQuote.blotName = 'custom-blockquote';
  CustomBlockQuote.tagName = 'blockquote';
  CustomBlockQuote.className = 'custom-class-name';
  Quill.register(CustomBlockQuote, true);
```

I have just created a jsfiddle as an example, I hope it works for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/hassansalem/095mh3fn/4/